# grunt: I am having some errors in package.json

Tags: gruntjs

I have Task Run Explore and I installed grunt in my solution. I am getting some errors in package.json but I don't understand because I used to created it npm init.

Errors are:

Sequence contains no elements:

```
Failed to run "C:\_DEVELOP\C#\my_circle\my_circle\package.json"...
Sequence contains no elements
Failed to run "C:\_DEVELOP\C#\my_circle\my_circle\Gruntfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c grunt -b "C:\_DEVELOP\C#\my_circle\my_circle" --gruntfile "C:\_DEVELOP\C#\my_circle\my_circle\Gruntfile.js" --tasks "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\TaskRunnerExplorer\Scripts" vs-grunt-task-reader

Failed to run "C:\_DEVELOP\C#\my_circle\my_circle\package.json"...
Sequence contains no elements
```

It is when I change in combo to0 use GruntFile.js.

in node_modules I have installed: `grunt-cli, grunt-contrib-jshint, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-watch`, they are inside `node_modules` inside the project level.

My GruntFile.js is:

```
/// <binding Clean='uglify, watch' />
module.exports = function ( grunt )
{
    var bannerContent = '/*********************************************************\n' +
                        ' my_circle ' +
                        ' ==> Fecha subida:' +
                        ' <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy hh:MM") %>\n ' +
                        '*********************************************************/\n\n';

    //definir las tareas
    grunt.initConfig( {

        uglify: {
            options: {
                spawn: false,
                compress: false,
                mangle: false,
                beautify: true,
                banner: bannerContent
            },
            js: {
                src: ["Scripts/*.js"],
                dest: "Scripts/output.min.js"
            }
        }


    } );
    //para cargar los plugins 
    grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-uglify' );

    //registrar los plugins a las tareas por defecto. si ejecuto grunt ejecuta por orden los siguientes plugins.
    grunt.registerTask( 'default', ['uglify'] );
};
```

What is wrong in my code and package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mads Kristensen this is a bug:
https://github.com/madskristensen/NpmTaskRunner/issues/12

> I've investigated the issue and there is nothing that can be done from this extension to fix it. The issue lies with the Task Runner Explorer extensibility code and I've opened an internal bug (176952) on the VS Web Team to fix it. Closing it here.

I see the same behaviour